# $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition for limit to inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know how the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition works for usual limit involving equality:
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta>0\ s.t.\ 0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon
$$

But what if we want an inequality $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \ge L$? How should the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition look like in this case?

Comment: The laziest way at least would just be to append a $\forall M \ge L$ to the start of the right-hand side, and replace $L$ with $M$ thereafter.

Comment: Presumably, you want the existential quantifier: $\exists M \geq L$ such that $f(x) \to M$ as $x \to a$.

Comment: There is a pretty natural way to alter the definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ into a definition of $\liminf_{x\to a} f(x) \ge L$: just change $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ into $f(x)-L>-\varepsilon$. But the notation $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \ge L$ assumes that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ actually exists, which is not guaranteed. Therefore I don't see any better way than the $\exists M\ge L$ quantifier already suggested.

Comment: @GregMartin How did you establish the condition of $f(x)-L>-\varepsilon$? Also, if I were to consider the extended real number (i.e. limit exists in the sense that infinities are allowed), will your first definition work?

Comment: Some limits just don't exist—for example, $\lim_{x\to0} \sin\frac1x$.